# Getting Columns Related to GROUP BY Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

I'd like to do something like the following.

```
SELECT aspnet_Users.UserName, aspnet_Membership.Email, count(*) as Activities
FROM aspnet_Users
     INNER JOIN Activities ON aspnet_Users.UserId = Activities.ActUserID
     INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership ON aspnet_Users.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId
     WHERE Activities.ActDateTime >= GETDATE()
     GROUP BY aspnet_Users.UserName
     ORDER BY Activities DESC
```

But this gives me an error.

> Column 'aspnet_Membership.Email' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I understand the error somewhat. I'm trying to select a column that is not part of the grouping.

However, there will always be a one-to-one relationship between aspnet_Membership.Email and aspnet_Users.UserId. So how would I implement this?

Comment: What relevance does the relationship between Email and UserId have? Why do you want to select Email but not want to group by it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
GROUP BY aspnet_Users.UserId
```

To:

```
GROUP BY aspnet_Users.UserName, aspnet_Membership.Email
```

Not sure why you think you need to mention the UserId column in the grouping if you don't want to return it, or why you think you shouldn't group by the columns you *do* want to return.

Comment: Sorry, some of the different edits I was making to get it working crept in to my question (now corrected). Yes, your suggestion works. However, I'm not at all clear how. If there's a one-to-one relationship between the two `GROUP BY` columns, will the `SELECT`ed columns always reflect that single relationship? And, what does the statement do if there is not a one-to-one relationship between the two columns? Thanks for any additional tips.

Comment: I'm not following your question. Can you show some sample data that represent the one-to-one relationship, and some sample data "if there is not a one-to-one relationship"?

Answer (score 0):

to select a column it must either be in a group by clause or aggregated ,you could consider grouping by (aspnet_Users.UserName, aspnet_Membership.Email,aspnet_Users.UserId ) .

my guess is it would work